# Is it possible to release more than one version of my game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to release a new version of my unitygame, and how would I do this? Can I  just release a new version by creating a new copy of the game with changes and stuff like that? Just can i simply edit a released game in unity?

Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to ?

Comment: what platform are you going to be using? what retail channel (ios store? andriod store? etc.) there isn't a technical limitation within unity to what builds you create, tweak and build as you like, but how you get those builds to market will likely be the issue.

Comment: @MXD I think the OP would like to modify the released game, which probably means the executable. In that case, I think you cannot do it...

Comment: @nbro even then it is still possible using version control and a server. But you would have to keep it in mind from the start.

Comment: that platform i whant to relase the game on is Windows. Why i ask this is to make a game that works and don't turning my own game into a mess.

Comment: Hmm... mayby i can just create a new project and add al the sceans from the old game into the new game, add new stuff and make it into the new version?

Comment: Now i get it! If you go to file/buildsetting and click build and run or just build your game is builded. But if you allredy have build the game and build it agin you just make another file that is the same game that before, but with all the changes. So you can say it is a "new version". If this is wrong please rell me wath is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit your existing project and then build your game again.
Users need to delete the old version of game and then re-install the new version.